# How to make ComboBox caption bold in Vaadin?

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin7

I created my own style in styles.scss:

```
.p-bold-caption .v-caption .v-captiontext {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Then in the code I add the style like so:

```
myComboBox.setStyleName("p-bold-caption");
```

Nothing happens. It's still not bolded. How to do this? I suck at css, but I've managed to make and use my own styles in the styles.scss. Not sure if I'm doing the css-selector syntax correctly here.

Comment: try `myComboBox.setPrimaryStyleName("p-bold-caption");`

Comment: Tried. It changed the style of the combobox in other ways but still no bolded caption.

Comment: What's the parent layout of your ComboBox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Css can be:

```css
.v-caption-p-bold-caption .v-captiontext {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

and please don't forget to recompile theme and clean browser cache.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. This worked WHEN I used the style with the method addStyleName("p-bold-caption") and NOT when using setPrimaryStyleName-method. Still not sure why I had to name it like .v-caption-p-bold-caption. Can you elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: @SteveWaters it is about component div structure or, better to say, current component implementation. :)

Comment: I see. Thank you. In other words, I really should just finally read that css no crap primer :) http://wendypeck.com/css101.html

Answer (score 1):

```
    ComboBox cbDropdown = new ComboBox();
    cbDropdown.setCaptionAsHtml(true);
    cbDropdown.setCaption("<h2><b>"+ pDisplayName +"</b></h2>");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).